# how to resolve the issue of outgoing message transfer between two different pools in camunda?

Tags: camunda

I have a problem When I use two or more pools in the same process diagram in Camunda process model, the simulation does not work well. In particular, it seems that tokens do not pass through the message flow and so the two pools work separately and not as well as a collaboration diagram.

How can I do to simulate a collaboration diagram?

Thanks

Comment: Which simulation are you talking about?

Comment: It is about the execution of the process in the camunda platform. In particular, when the process has two or more pools. the problem is that tokens do not pass through the message flow and so the two pools work separately and not as a collaboration diagram.    thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Camunda, you need to implement a message throw event like you would implement a service task, that means by providing code that delivers the message. There is no default delivery of messages. The engine ignores message connections in a collaboration diagram.

Resources to read:

- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/#message-api
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/#message-intermediate-throwing-event

Comment: thank you for your reply. Do you have an idea how to implement it or an example that treats this problem.